# Apache Camel: How to retain original attachments after split?

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using the [Split EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc), trying to either access all attachments from the original in message or to copy all attachments from the original in message to the in message of the sub-exchange.

I've found that this works, but it looks strange to me:

```
…
// Save attachments in some header:
.setHeader("savedAttachments", new Expression() {
    @Override
    public <T> T evaluate(final Exchange exchange, final Class<T> aClass) {
        return (T) exchange.getIn().getAttachments();
    }
})
.split(…)
// Restore attachments:
.process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setAttachments((Map<String, DataHandler>) it.getIn().getHeader("savedAttachments")))
…
```

Is this how to do it? Or is there a better way?

I've also tried several combinations of       `context.setAllowUseOriginalMessage(true);` and `.split(…).shareUnitOfWork()` and `exchange.getUnitOfWork().getOriginalInMessage().getAttachments()` but I couldn't access the original attachments that way.

Thanks

John

Comment: What version of Camel do you use? And which component do you use that uses attachments, AFAIR there are only a few like mail components etc, or some of the SOAP-WS components.

Comment: Latest Camel 2.23.1. In this specific case, it's a custom endpoint that sets attachments at the upstream IN message to pass a collection of files through the process which will be needed downstream. While the split pattern keeps all headers in the split messages, it does not keep the original attachments. Is this intentional or more like an omission? Should split maybe have an option to control keeping the attachments?

Comment: @ClausIbsen Would you second my opening an issue on that? The split documentation should state that attachments are not preserved in the split messages. Would be even better, if split kept the attachments. Or, if that is considered too risky because of backward compatibility, let the split method have an option (or builder option method) to enable keeping the original attachments.